# Cannot Hide Data Field in Visio Org Chart

Tags: charts, visio

I am creating an org chart from an excel spreadsheet. Each row has Employee Name and Job Title, but also Employee ID and Supervisor Employee ID (both number data types).

I am using the Organization Chart Wizard to automatically create an org chart as a starting point (its pretty big). In doing so, I use the two numeric fields in the "name" and "reports to" fields because we have employees with the same name. However, I do not want these numerical fields displayed in the org chart shapes. You can see in the second picture I cannot remove the three default fields from the chosen "Shape Data Fields."

[image: Options for "Name" and "Reports to" Fields]

[image: I cannot Remove any of these three]

Here's what the shapes look like, I want to remove the number field altogether. Regardless of the shape stencil I select, I get the same behavior.

[image: I want to remove the digit]

If I try to delete the shape, I get the error "shape protection, container and/or layer properties prevent complete execution." Even when I go to Developer -> Protection -> Unlock, the issue persists. Thus, it must be an issue with the container or layer properties.

Lastly, this page has a "To Delete a data field" section at the bottom. I tried exactly this, and the fields were removed from the **Define Shape Data** box, but the shapes remained unchanged, still showing all fields:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-data-to-shapes-09272394-5243-4e1b-bcfa-425a8b4d1ce2?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Answer (score 0):

Tweak the master you want to use by decorticating its structure.
In the drawing explorer check whether the shape (the master) is group or a single shape. Find out where the ID (the 3rd field) is used for display, adjust accordingly by correcting the shapesheet.

Sorry for such a generic explanation. If we could exchange files, I would have had a look at your master and could have corrected it.

HTH, Y.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and eventually found that I could prevent the ID field (used in Name) from displaying, using Display Options - on the **Org Chart** tab, using the dialog box launcher button (bottom-right) in the **Shapes** section.

The ID field is shown as 'Name' under **Block 2** - you can use the drop-down to set this to 'None' (so that it doesn't display at all), or pick one of the other fields that you chose to display in its place.